# WSO2 getting custom error messages and codes

Tags: wso2, properties-file, wso2-enterprise-integrator, custom-errors

When I am getting any exception in my sequence or when I am calling any endpoint which gives me some exception,  I want to set custom error messages and error codes in the exception output. I want to read/get these error codes and error messages somewhere from properties file or any other way(like DB).

If I change any error messages on runtime, then I do not want to touch my sequence code.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Appreciate any hint or pointer on this. I am using WSO2 EI 6.3 version.

BR//
Vipin Nirwal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read custom error messages from a DB, then you can use a DBLookup mediator in the fault sequence or inside your onError sequence. Or if you want to read from a file, you can use a File Connector to read it.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/DBLookup+Mediator
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector#WorkingwiththeFileConnector-read